# IntelliJ : the "Clone" button doesn't clone my git repository

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I'm trying to clone an existing Git repository with IntelliJ.

In the welcome screen, I open "Check out from Version Control"/"Git", fill all the fields, click on "Test" to make sure that the (HTTPS) URL is correct, and double-check that the "Parent Directory" I gave does exist. Then I click on "Clone".

Then the "Clone Repository" window closes, I'm back on the welcome screen, and that's all. No directory has been created in the Parent Directory, and I can't find a copy of my repository anywhere. No error message, no nothing.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Look for any errors in ide log - Help->Show log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like git client is not installed, or not configured - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135954

Comment: That was it, thank you. Not warning the user looks like a bug.

Comment: Yes, that is a bug. See the mentioned report on YouTrack